# Strange plus signs in bootstrap css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

There's something strange going on in my `bootstrap` `css` code. I'm seeing strange plus signs that shouldn't be there, and I'm not finding any reason for them to be there.

Here's an example (you may have to zoom in, they're very small):

[image]

This is the `html` (I left it mostly untouched as it appears in the `view source` so as not to eliminate anything that may cause the problem):

```
<div align="left" class="col-xs-5 col-sm-7 col-md-7 searchresultbg" style="border:0px solid red; margin-top:10px;">                         
<div class="hidden-xs" style="border:0px solid red;"><br />
                          <a href="http://rover.ebay.com/rover/1/711-53200-19255-0/1?ff3=2&amp;toolid=10044&amp;campid=5337720480&amp;customid=999999999999999&amp;lgeo=1&amp;vectorid=229466&amp;item=121697860181" target="_blank">Strange Dragon  vol.3  Hana to Yume Comics / Manga Comic from Japan</a> <br />
                      </div>
<div class="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg" style="border:0px solid red;"><br />
                          <a href="http://rover.ebay.com/rover/1/711-53200-19255-0/1?ff3=2&amp;toolid=10044&amp;campid=5337720480&amp;customid=999999999999999&amp;lgeo=1&amp;vectorid=229466&amp;item=121697860181" target="_blank">Strange Dragon  vol.3  Hana to Yume Comi [...]</a> <br />
</div>

<div class="hidden-xs" style="border:0px solid red;"><br /></div>

<div style="border:0px solid blue;">
                             Fixed Price<br />
                             Listed: Jul 07 2015 at 11:07AM<br />                                
                             Time Left: 6d 22h 0m<br />
                          </div>                              

                          <!-- site logo -->
<div class="hidden-xs"><br /></div><img src="/app/javax.faces.resource/ebaylogo.png.xhtml?ln=images" class="img-responsive maxwidth70 bottom-buffer10" />                           
</div>
```

This happens on all browsers. Any ideas why?

EDIT: I'm using a gray background image to the entire row. Here's the `css`:

```
.searchresultbg {
    background-image:url('../resources/images/searchresultbg.jpg');
    border-radius: 8px;
}
```

I've checked and the image is spotless.

Comment: are you using any image as grey background image in class 'searchresultbg' or other.

Comment: If you can reproduce the "error" on JSFiddle, it would help us see what goes wrong.

Comment: What happens when you inspect that `+` sign?

Comment: @MikePhils, yes, I do. I'm editing the question with the css. But I did check the image and the plus signs are not there.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I'm not seeing anything unusual when I'm inspecting the element. How would I know if there's anything suspect?

Comment: probably you have must typed '+' in you DOM or HTML by mistakenly. search + in files.

Comment: @MikePhils I already did. Nothing.

Comment: @Zeratops this contains the bootstrap css files so no, I can't reproduce it on JFiddle.

Comment: You can add the Bootstrap CSS to jsfiddle by using a CDN that supports it > http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/  Just click on External Resources in the left panel in jsfiddle and add what you need.

Comment: I'm not seeing any plus signs in your picture....

Comment: Look closer at the area circled with a red marker.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `border-radius` is causing this as a result of four rounded corners meeting, as opposed to a phantom "+" symbol.

What happens when you remove it?

```
.searchresultbg {
  background-image: url('../resources/images/searchresultbg.jpg');
}
```

Also, you *can* include external CSS in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net). Check out the **External Resources** option from the menu, or simply use `@import` in your CSS, like so:

```
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css');
```

Comment: Removing the border radius doesn't change anything, but if I remove the background image the plus signs disappear (I changed the page's white background to something else so I can see it.) The image itself though is clean, I double checked.

Comment: From the screenshot you provided, it *definitely* looks like a border radius issue. Can you try putting the following in your CSS as a test: `* { border-radius: 0px !important; }`

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use a background color instead of the picture. So this is the `css`:

```
.searchresultbg {
    /*background-image:url('../resources/images/searchresultbg.jpg');*/
    border-radius: 8px;
}
.container-fluid .searchresultbg{background:#f2f2f2!important;}
```

The silly plus signs disappeared and all is well.